# How to call a url on a specific GCP compute server using Java?

Tags: java, api, http, java-8, google-compute-engine

I have this Java method that lists all instances in a managed compute-engine group:

```
public List<ManagedInstance> listInstancesInManagedGroup(String groupName, String zoneName) throws IOException {
    Compute.InstanceGroupManagers.ListManagedInstances listInstances =
            compute.instanceGroupManagers().listManagedInstances(projectId, zoneName, groupName);
    try {
        return listInstances.execute().getManagedInstances();
    } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println(groupName + " group not created yet.");
        return null;
    }
}
```

I now want to call a GET and POST HTTP request on each of them.

What's the API to execute an HTTP request on a specific instance? I couldn't find the way in the compute [API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/)

Comment: This is a Java question instead of GCE question. Just get the public IP of the instance and the service port, call it from Java as any other HTTP server. Search "Java HTTP client". BTW, you need to have a GCE firewall rule to allow the traffic.

Comment: I try to get `the public IP of the instance` but there is no such property.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40175519/whats-the-way-to-get-in-java-a-gcp-managed-instance-external-ip

Comment: We don't usually get public IP programmatically, just go to the web console to check, or use `gcloud compute instances describe <instance-name>`.

Comment: but it's dynamic, so i have to do this programatically

Comment: Then you need instances.get API https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/get . BTW, you can consider use static IP instead of ephemeral.